Excel sorting by a numeric value within a string
We have a large Excel spreadsheet with a bunch of fragrances. We are using this to import to our website. Many of them are the same fragrance but different sized bottles.
The main column we are using to sort has the name of the fragrance followed by the size in ml. This results in a string with a number towards, but not all the way at, the end: Fragrance 1 30ml
In Excel 2016, if for a specific fragrance there is a 30ml and 50ml bottle then it's in order because the first differing character, the "3" and "5" sort correctly. But of course, when you have one that has 100ml or 200ml bottles, these are sorted above the 30ml and 50ml bottles making the order incorrect. As the website imports directly from this spreadsheet, we need Excel to order this correctly, by name and then by increasing number.
Is there a way to sort these in some way so they are smallest first (even if I need to add formulas to new columns next to it)?
Bear in mind, There are a lot of columns with other information about each product so it will need to be able to be filtered to keep the other attributes in line with the same product
Example of how it is:



Bottle




Fragrance 1 100ml


Fragrance 1 200ml


Fragrance 1 30ml


Fragrance 1 50ml




Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Is there any chance of having an extra column for the size in ml as a simple number?

I will need that eventually which should be easy enough. But for sorting it wouldnt work out from what i understand

If you split your Bottle column into at 2 separate columns then you should be able to perform a multi-column sort.

You need to extract the numbers and sort by them. In this case, the number is between the last space and "ml". So here we can use the formula:
=SORTBY(A2:A5,--TEXTBEFORE(TEXTAFTER(A2:A5," ",-1),"ml"))


In version 2016, you can use auxiliary columns. In the first one (col. G in the screenshot) we place a fragment denoting the base name, in the second (col. L) – the capacity of the packaging (number). I used the formulas:
col. G: =LEFT(A9,SEARCH("ml",A9)-LEN(L9)-2)
col. L: =--RIGHT(SUBSTITUTE(LEFT(A9,SEARCH("ml",A9)-1)," ",REPT(" ",10)),10)
Select all the data and perform a standard sorting according to two criteria: the first is the name from column G, the second is the number from column L.
Auxiliary columns can be hidden.


Hey MGonet, thnk you so much for this!  However, on some of them, they do have a word after the ml. Most of them actually. some of them have 100ml Spray. Some have 100ml Spray - Oceanic Edition.
Is it possible to just edit this formula to be -2? and sort out the few that might be left at the end?

In fact, it seems I dont have a sortby function at all

First thing: which version of Excel? Second: more different examples. You need to find a rule to separate a number from your description.

Im back on 2016 still here. I see sortby is 2021 or 365 sadly. 95% are Spray at the end of description. If I can sort spray only, thats perfect
some more examples:
Burberry Hero Parfum 100ml Spray
Burberry Hero Parfum 200ml Refill
Burberry Hero Parfum 50ml Spray
Davidoff Cool Water Woman Eau de Toilette 100ml Spray
Davidoff Cool Water Woman Eau de Toilette 100ml Spray - Oceanic Edition
Davidoff Cool Water Woman Eau de Toilette 30ml Spray
Davidoff Cool Water Woman Eau de Toilette 50ml Spray
This is really the only different ones there are

I have added an alternative solution proposal suitable for the 2016 version.

this has worked an absolute treat!! Beyond appreciative of your help. Thank you so much

@CNLSElectronics In case you haven't seen it: What should I do when someone answers my question?
